# What does the `i` variable in `times { |i| ... }` stand for?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to read code for understanding. basically what this code is supposed to do is take a string called `new_str` (whose number chars are always a multiple of 5) and put its chars into another string called `new_str_2` in groups of 5 followed by a space. For instance if the `new_str` was `"onetwothre"`, `new_str_2` would be `"onetw other"`. but my question what does the variable `i` do in tho `.times` block?

```
new_str = "thisisyetanotherstringwithoutspaces"
new_str_2 = ""
(new_str.size / 5).times { |i| new_str_2 << new_str[i * 5, 5] << " " }
new_str_2 #=> "thisi syeta nothe rstri ngwit houts paces "
```

Comment: `(new_str.size / 5).times { |i| puts i }` should give some insight.

Comment: Have you read the [`Integer#times`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Integer.html#method-i-times) documentation?

Answer (score 1):

If there's a block given with variable like you did there, it'll count from 0 to `(new_str.size / 5) - 1`

[Doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Integer.html#method-i-times)

Answer (score 1):

```
(new_str.size / 5).times { |i| new_str_2 << new_str[i * 5, 5] << " " }
```

is an enumerator followed by a block. The enumerator, an instance of the class [Enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html), is

```
enum = (new_str.size / 5).times
  #=> #<Enumerator: 7:times>
```

We can examine the elements of this enumerator by converting it to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

When Ruby sees an enumerator followed by a block she sends the method [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-each) to the enumerator:

```
enum.each { |i| new_str_2 << new_str[i * 5, 5] << " " }
  #=> 7
new_str_2
  #=> "thisi syeta nothe rstri ngwit houts paces "
```

`each` passes each element of `enum` to the block, setting the block variable(s) equal to its value. We can use the method [Enumerator@next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) to see how this is done:

```
i = enum.next #=> 0
i = enum.next #=> 1
i = enum.next #=> 2
...
```

The block calculation is performed for each value of `i`.

Now let's consider a second example:

```
[[1,2], [3,4]].map { |a| a[0] + a[1] }
  #=> [3,7]
enum = [[1,2], [3,4]].map
  #=> #<Enumerator: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]:map> 
enum.to_a
  #=> [[1, 2], [3, 4]] 
enum.each { |a| a[0] + a[1] }
  #=> [3, 7] 
a = enum.next
  #=> [1, 2] 
a[0] + a[1] 
  #=> 3 
a = enum.next
  #=> [3, 4] 
a[0] + a[1] 
  #=> 7
```

Often you would see this written

```
[[1,2], [3,4]].map { |a,b| a + b }
  #=> [3,7]
```

which arguably is more clear. The steps are as before, except the assignment of values to the block variables uses *parallel assignment* (aka *multiple assignment*):

```
enum = [[1,2], [3,4]].map
  #=> #<Enumerator: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]:map> 
a,b = enum.next
  #=> [1, 2]
a #=> 1 
b #=> 2 
a + b
  #=> 3 
a,b = enum.next
  #=> [3, 4] 
a #=> 3 
b #=> 4 
a + b
  #=> 7
```

Parallel assignment of values to block variables can be used to advantage in many situations. Here's one more that uses the method [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
[[1,2], [3,4]].each_with_object({}) { |(a,b),h| h[a] = b }
  #=> {1=>2, 3=>4} 

enum = [[1,2], [3,4]].each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]:each_with_object({})> 
enum.to_a
  #=> [[[1, 2], {}], [[3, 4], {}]] 

(a,b),h = enum.next
  #=> [[1, 2], {}] 
a #=> 1 
b #=> 2 
h #=> {} 
h[a] = b
  #=> 2 
h #=> {1=>2} 

(a,b),h = enum.next
  #=> [[3, 4], {1=>2}] 
a #=> 3 
b #=> 4 
h #=> {1=>2} 
h[a] = b
  #=> 4 
h #=> {1=>2, 3=>4}
```

Note that [Enumerator#each_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html) (the `Enumerator` counterpart of `Enumerable#each_with_object`) could be used for the problem at hand:

```
(new_str.size / 5).times.with_object('') { |i,new_str_2|
  new_str_2 << new_str[i * 5, 5] << " " }
  #=> "thisi syeta nothe rstri ngwit houts paces "
```

Answer (score 0):

The `i` is what gets yielded to the code `new_str_2 << new_str[i * 5, 5] << " "` from `(new_str.size / 5).times`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(new_str.size / 5).times { |i| new_str_2 << new_str[i * 5, 5] << " " }
```

To make things easier, `new_str.size / 5` evaluates to `7`. So your expression is the same as:

```
7.times { |i| new_str_2 << new_str[i * 5, 5] << " " }
```

This goes through your code block *7 times* starting from `i=0` upto `i=6`. So to begin with we have `i=0` is passed into the block. Then the following steps occur:

1. `{ |i| new_str_2 << new_str[i * 5, 5] << " " }`
2. `{ |i=0| new_str_2 << new_str[0 * 5, 5] << " " }`
3. `{ |i=0| new_str_2 << new_str[0, 5] << " " }`
4. `{ |i=0| new_str_2 << "thisi " }`

The `times` iterator then does the same for `i=1` and so on upto `i=6`.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, variables declared inside `||` in a block declaration are “input” arguments.

Given, you have a function called `foo` which can take a block, you can use it as following:

```
foo(method, arguments) do
  do something: funny
end
```

The block will then be executed *inside* `foo` method, at the place the method wants to execute it; that way the code can easily alter behaviour of the method.

In some cases the block may pass some parameters to you. You can declare them inside the `||` block, and generally speaking are optional to declare, in case you don’t want to use them. Syntax for that is following:

```
foo(method, arguments) do |first, second|
  my_method(first)
  puts second
end
```

So in case of `times` method, it passes the argument from inside the `times` method, in a loop. Its internal definition could be something like

```
def times count
  i = 0
  while i < count
    yield(i)
    i+=1
  end
end
```

which would cause your block to be called multiple times, with each time giving `i` as argument.